# How to build a relay switch that resets when power goes out?

Tags: digital-logic, relay

I'm trying to build a kill switch in my car so that when I turn the ignition, a button also has to be held down. When the power goes through, the button can be let go and the system stays closed until the car shuts down, then you have to repeat the process. I came up with this diagram:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcvVN.jpg
[image]

What kind of parts does it take to build this? I drew logic gates but I have no idea how that translates to real components. Is a button and relay from an electronics store enough? I'm worried about 1) splitting the ignition wire like that and 2) how much power actually loops back, would things over heat?

Comment: Does your car use a starter motor to turn over the engine? Because, if it does, all you need to do is buy a momentary switch capable of handling the required current to the starter motor and wire it in series. (Or use a relay and a smaller momentary switch.)

Comment: @jonk cranking current is pretty high. I wouldn't want to put my thumb on that switch.

Comment: Starters in all cars (except BMC mini's) is switched by a solenoid. The key current is only a few amps.

Comment: I've put my thumb on a starter switch, (it was the back end of the starter pull in a morris 1100). the engine cranked.  nothing exciting happened.

Comment: Starter motors are used in diesel engines only, right? Mine is a gasoline engine (USA, the only kind I'm familiar with). From what I understand there's only an ignition coil/solenoid that is used to fire off the spark plugs. And diesel needs a compressor to get the air to ignite. Do you know if that compressor needs to keep running or of that is the starter motor?  I'll look it up later

Comment: Also there is a starter wire, for the solenoid, but I don't want to use that because someone said that with that disabled and the fuel pump working, the engine would get flooded. Now whether that is worse than repeatedly dry firing spark plugs (which I think worst case would just drain the battery) I don't know, but it seems like the most common kill switch is with the fuel pump so I'm just going to follow that idea

Comment: Starter motors are used with both gas and diesel engines - they crank the engine.  Both types of engine do their own compressing of the air or air/fuel mixture.  You stop a gas engine by turning off the electric ignition system.  You stop a deisel by stopping fuel delivery from the fuel injection pump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you use a relay wired so that the live side of the switch powers the relay coil. 
the button used should be capable of powering the whole switched load

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxCaBr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

by adding a diode the load can be isolated fronm the button allowing the use of a smaller button that only needs to pass the relay coil current (about 0.1A)

Comment: Thank you. I saw the first pic and thought OK I have no idea what's going on this looks legit, after understanding the diode that makes even more sense. Thank you

Comment: So you also mention automotive relays, would you recommend those over one I get in a Fry's or Micro center?

Comment: the quick connect terminals and mounting tab on automotive relays mean you can use them without using a PCB or an enclosure